# Why was this question about L5 closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked the following question:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/are-there-going-to-be-any-more-episodes-of-l5

Which isn't a speculation imho. I wondered if there are going to be any more episodes. And since it's a low budget production there isn't very much information to find. Hence I asked here to see if anyone else knows more about it.

It got closed as:

> Questions about release dates and speculation on a series airdates are considered Off-Topic as per the FAQ. As always, if you would like to dispute this, I encourage you to open a question up on Movies and TV Meta

But I am not asking about air dates.

**Update**

My question could be boiled down to a simple yes/no question as in `Yes, there will be more episodes` / `No, there will not be more episodes`.

A good answer would have been:

`Yes, they are going to use kickstart.com to try to fund more episodes` or `No, it was just an experiment to try to see if a scifi tv series could be funded entirely through crowd sourcing`.

Back to the faq:

I do understand that questions about air dates, dvd releases etc are off topic. But imho this is not that type of question.

Neither are I'm asking about rumors. I want facts. It's a low budget tv series. The requested information might be in a sci-fi fan site or whatever. I'm not into the whole DIY tv series scene. That's why I'm asking.

The question would not produce a discussion like in a forum, and that's the most important aspect of off topic questions. Right?

Finally, no answers would mean that nobody knows what I'm asking. Which is an answer by itself.

***Quoting TylerShads:***

> Either way, it is a question only answerable by the production company if the info is not readily available.

Well. Ok. I can agree on that. The problem is that there isn't a company behind the series and the team (which have a crappy homepage) could have posted in some sort of community site.

Comment: One problem with no answer being an answer is that one of the goals of the SE network is to have a high answer rate.  Also, without a company behind production, then that solidifies it as an unanswerable question.

Comment: `One problem with no answer being an answer is that one of the goals of the SE network is to have a high answer rate`. I doubt that the team behind SE would reason like that. The question IS answerable just like I reasoned.

Answer (score 3):

thank you for taking the time to ask a meta question, you may not believe me but I think it is good when people challenge the FAQ so that we can make sure that the site is being directed in a way that the users want.

Personally I think that the question whilst not specifically speculating about dates, and asking for concrete information - it is a question about the airing of a show and therefore currently excluded in the FAQ.

You may ask - why is that in the FAQ then?  Why can't we ask questions about the future of TV shows and movies, if backed with sources or references?

The main issues as far as I am concerned is that any such answer to such a question about if or when a movie will be made or when it will be made available on DVD or broadcast in a particularly country is that it is too localized.  You may get an answer suitable for someone in the USA, when you want an answer in Sweden or available on DVD or whatever.  An answer to this question is also perhaps more importantly localized in time - it is suitable for now, when the question is asked - and may go out of date.  Your question would be far better answered on a forum IMHO.

Comment: I'm trying to find if the show is going to get any more episodes at all. i.e. if the production is going to continue since they successfully managed to fund the first episode through crowd sourcing. How can that be too localized? Or why do you continue to speak about dates?

Comment: The question has been closed as by the current definition in our FAQ it is off topic.  It is a question about the future of a tv-show or movie.  Arguing about whether 'if' is any more or less about the future than 'when' is not going to get us anywhere.  If you disagree with this, please ask a meta question proposing that we start to allow questions like this and see what sort of response you get.

Answer (score 2):

But you are asking about something listed in the FAQ as off-topic:

> A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.

As an elaboration.  I take this question as a question on the decision of a production company which, taking a theme out of [gaming.se](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)'s FAQ

> Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases

Which is pretty self explanatory.  Either way, it is a question *only* answerable by the production company if the info is not readily available.

As my fellow mod said, I do thank you for challenging what is in the FAQ as it helps us grow as a site.

Comment: The purpose of the Moderators is to apply the rules of the community - and I agree with TylerShads that this is a question speculating about the possible airing of a series, even if 'dates' are not specifically asked for - and under the current FAQ this is off-topic.  It would be interesting to see whether someone disagrees and we can have a 'vote off' over this.  I don't want to have the moderator-mafia decision here - but the community.

Comment: @iandotkelly: I fully aware of the role of the community and the moderators. I'm active in several sites if you check my SE profile.

Comment: @jgauffin - I was not claiming otherwise - I was just saying to anyone reading, please join in and comment or vote if you think that this should be on-topic.  We should not make the rules.